# How to check type of properties of an empty class object in Typescript + angular?

Tags: typescript

```
Class Test{
  constructor(
     public a: number,
     public b: string
   ) {}
}
let t = new Test();
```

How do I check the type of t.a or t.b programmatically?

Comment: you mean `typeof t === "number"` and `typeof t === "string"`?

Comment: That's the point of TypeScript: that code wouldn't compile, because you didn't pass any argument to the constructor, which expects a number and a string. If you pass something else (except any, which means: don't care about types), it won't compile. So, most of the time, you don't need to do any type check. The compiler does them for you. What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript should check that type of error in compile time. But if we get data from outside - TypeScript can't help, we want a runtime type check - [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts)

io-ts exaple:

```
const Person = t.type({
  name: t.string,
  age: t.number
})

// runtime check
const result = Person.decode({ name: 'Giulio' })

console.log(PathReporter.report(result))
// => ['Invalid value undefined supplied to : { name: string, age: number }/age: number']

ThrowReporter.report(result)
// => throws 'Invalid value undefined supplied to : { name: string, age: number }/age: number'

interface IPerson extends t.TypeOf<typeof Person> {}

function getName(person: IPerson): string{
  return person.name;
}

// compile time check
getName({ name: 'Giulio' });
```